# WHEN to get teachers and counselors gifts/cards for writing college recs?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I asked two of my teachers for college recommendations towards the end of my junior year in high school. My counselor is automatically going to write a recommendation also. I am assuming they are going to write it over the summer. When should I get them thank you cards/gifts? I have researched all over and have found information on what to give but I don't know when the best time is. Should I give it right after asking them? Or maybe wait until senior year is over? Please help thanks

Comment: Sorry, your question is about high school etiquette, but this site is about graduate school and research at universities (and etiquette there tends to be very different from high school). It's not a bad question, just out of the scope of this site. (See the [help/on-topic].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference for thank you's/gifts was to give them after acceptance. That way you can tell them where you were accepted, in addition to expressing thanks for their time! Letter writers are interested in hearing that they are helping you get where you want to go (an added bonus for having their time and effort appreciated)!

My two cents anyway.